# Horizontal scrollbar displayed because absolute positioned elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, ion-range-slider

In a webshop, i have some sliders on my categoria page.
With these sliders, i can filter products between those price.

My problem is, that on mobile devices, the horizontal scrollbar is displayed, because these sliders have absolute position, and the left or right value for that, is calculated by javascript i think.

What can i do with this? The slider plugin name is: Ion range slider.

[If you want to check the site, you can do it here:](https://projektar.hu/kategoria/9/szamitastechnika/ssd-meghajto)

[image: Photo of the problem]

```
<div class="filters_container">
                    <input id="range_03" value="" name="" >
                    <input name="price_from" id="price_from" type="hidden" value="26656">
                    <input name="price_to" id="price_to" type="hidden" value="50533">
                    <input name="slider_from" id="slider_from" type="hidden" value="26656">
                    <input name="slider_to" id="slider_to" type="hidden" value="50533">
                </div>
```

Comment: have you tried `overflow-x: hidden` or `overflow-x: auto`?

Comment: Yes, i added it to the body. But on mobile, i can still move the horizontaly,

Comment: not to the body, to the element that has the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: The body has it, on mobile devices.

Comment: In your Image, the horizontal scrollbar is not applied to the body, but an other element in your page.
just set the `overflow-x: hidden` to that element

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest adding padding in the **row** container, as the width of the selectors is out of the irs-bar context :

[image]